# creating zip of big folder with pdf files

Tags: php, pdf, zip

I'm creating zip of folder with pdf and txt files, its working well. but where I creating zip of folder with above 30 files ( 389 KB each file) i getting empty zip. why?

here's my code:

```
include("include/zip_min.inc");

if($_GET['create_zip'])
{
    include("include/zip_min.inc");

    $zipfile = new zipfile();

    $files_arr=scandir($_GET['path']);
    foreach ($files_arr as $folder)
    {

    if(( strpos("-".$folder,".pdf") || strpos("-".$folder,".TXT") ) )//&& $k<30
    {
$k++;

        $fileonserver = $_GET['path']."/".$folder;//"path/to/file/oldfilename.txt";
        $filename =$folder;

     $zipfile -> addFile(file_get_contents($fileonserver), $filename);

    }
    }
    // Force download the zip
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.zip");
    echo $zipfile -> file();
}
```

Comment: have you manually specified/confirmed the path is correct?

Comment: How big are the files in the folder before they're zipped?

Comment: 389 KB each pdf file